# how to upgrade python software in linux operating system?

Tags: unix

Could anyone, please tell me how to upgrade python software in linux os. Currently python 2.6.5 version is installed. I want to remove and install 2.7 version. Any help would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to leave the system default alone.  The OS may include utilities that depend on the python engine that ships with it.

Instead, install [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), which allows you to manage different versions of python for different projects on the same system.